# How is $\frac{1}{x(\ln x)^2}$ decreasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I am new to integral testing, so my professor is trying to explain how to use the test on this series from **2 to infinity**, and it already satisfies the 1st condition by saying "it is obviously decreasing" and moving on to evaluate. How is it **obviously** decreasing?
I differentiated the function to get $\dfrac{2+\ln x}{x^2 (\ln x)^3}$, but still couldn't easily spot where is it below $0$. So is it right to say that any $x$ value below $1$ will make $f'(x)$ negative, and this is where $f(x)$ is decreasing?
I plotted it on the graph and it looks like, after $x=1$, $f(x)$ drops down and starts decreasing, so I don't know what to think anymore.
My understanding of this concept to test for convergence or divergence is hazy, so I would really appreciate if someone could provide clarity.

edit: i forgot there is minus sign for f '(x) so i clearly just confused myself for no reason.

Comment: Do you know that $x$ and $(\ln x)^2$ are both increasing on $(1,\infty)$?

Comment: Is your function $\frac{1}{x\ln(x)^2}$ or $\frac{1}{x}\ln(x)^2$?

Comment: @BernardMassé its the 1st one but (lnx)^2 not x^2

Comment: @UmbertoP. yes i know. could you please tell me how will that help ? iam little confused

Comment: Since both are increasing so is their product. What about the reciprocal of an increasing function?

Comment: @UmbertoP. ooooooh i seeeee. It decreases. omg thank you so much iam honestly tearing right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $g$, if $g(x)$ is increasing, then $\frac{1}{g(x)}$ is decreasing. Since $x$ is $(\ln x)^2$ are both increasing for $x>1$, $x(\ln x)^2$ is increasing and thus $\frac{1}{x(\ln x)^2}$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

For example: it is the product of two (positive) descending sequences ($\;x\ge 2\;$), or also:

$$f(x):=\frac1{x\log^2x}\implies f'(x)=-\frac{\log x+2}{x^2\log^3x}<0$$

for any $\;x\ge 2\;$

Comment: ooh iam sorry i just realized the derivative was wrong for missing the minus sign. thank you very much !